# Libreoffice Writer: How to flip/swap between two table rows?

Tags: libreoffice

I use latest LibreOffice Writer and I have a table with 4 rows

I want to flip/swap between the two middlish rows (row 2 and row 3).

That is, I want that row 3 will take the place of row 2 (or vice versa).

How can this be done automatically without manually copy-pasting the data from cell to cell (and then deleting the old data)?

The rows I work with are multi-columned (2 or more columns, so just dragging all data from one row to another isn't possible and will result in the dragging of just one particular cell from a set of cells).

### Update

If possible, I'd prefer a way that doesn't involve creating a third line to which we move the data (and then delete the original).

In other words I'll prefer a solution which is pure swapping or shall I say "replacing".

Comment: "If possible, I'd prefer a way that doesn't involve creating a third line to which we move the data" I don't think that is possible. Why is creating an extra line in the table a problem?

Comment: HI, it's surly not a problem, I just would prefer without this extra step if I can without - operational minimalism principle.

Comment: Indeed I'm sorry not to mention that when first publishing the question...

Comment: Related reading but not a complete solution: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=61692

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LibreOffice Writer v 6 right click on a line of the table and select inset row.
Then highlight the row you wish to move and whilst selected move it to the (now) blank new row.
Repeat for the second row you wish to move.

[Short video showing basic principles](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aea41oj3d9h6gh6/writer.ogv?dl=0)

Comment: @JohnDoea "so just dragging all data from one row to another isn't possible" it is if you follow the way shown in the video.. that is to say, to first highlight the data in the row you wish to move.

Comment: @JohnDoea replaced video link

Comment: +! for your blessed investment in this answer.

Comment: @JohnDoea Many thanks. I looked at alternatives but I don't think there are any.